# asp.net dropdownlist does not remember choice

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm currently running into a head-scratching bug in my ASP.NET Windows Form App. I have two `DropDownList`, implemented them in the same way, yet they behave differently.

**The problem:**

- When selecting an item in the DropDownList "GroepSelect", the page refreshes (as intended), but resets it's `SelectedIndex` to the first item.
- When selecting an item in the DropDownList "VakSelect", the page refreshes, but also remembers it's `SelectedIndex` value.

It's doing this behavior consistently, yet I am unable to discover what I do wrong.

**My Code:**

In my `HTML` code, I have two `DropDownList` Controls.

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="GroepSelect" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="VakSelect" AutoPostBack="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
</div>
```

I'm populating the controls in my C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Database db = new Database();
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            GroepSelect.DataSource = GenereerDummyGroepen(); // returns a List<ListItem>
            GroepSelect.DataTextField = "Text";
            GroepSelect.DataValueField = "Value";
            GroepSelect.DataBind();
            GroepSelect.SelectedValue = "1";

            VakSelect.DataSource = db.GetVakken(); // returns a List<Vak>
            VakSelect.DataTextField = "Omschrijving";
            VakSelect.DataValueField = "Id";
            VakSelect.DataBind();
            VakSelect.SelectedValue = "1";
        }

        // Use the SelectedValue to determine which data to get out of the database
        Medewerkers = db.GetMedewerkers(int.Parse(GroepSelect.SelectedValue));
        Opdracht = db.GetOpdrachten(int.Parse(VakSelect.SelectedValue)).First();
        Resultaten = db.GetResultaten(Opdracht.Id, int.Parse(GroepSelect.SelectedValue));

        GenereerTabel();
    }
```

As requested, my code for `GenereerDummyGroepen()` is the following:

```
private List<ListItem> GenereerDummyGroepen() {
        return new List<ListItem>()
            {
                new ListItem("Groep 1", "1"),
                new ListItem("Groep 2", "1")
            };
    }
```

**Why I implemented it this way?**

I try to populate a custom-made pivot table based on the content of `Medewerkers`, `Opdracht` and `Resultaten`. The content of those lists, depends on the selected item in the DropDownList control. The expected behavior of those controls is, that on the moment those are changed, the table should re-populate. The strategy I follow here, is that a page-postback is being processed, and using the `AppendDataBoundItems=true` remembers the DropDownList contents so that on the newly refreshed page I can generate the table.

**My Question**

I'm looking for the answer for: why is there a consistent different behavior? Is it the fact that the `ListItem` class differs in behavior from my custom class `Vak`?

Comment: Can you please put your code for GenereerDummyGroepen() method here.

Comment: @KevinShah Ugh, I made a fatal mistake in that method. Thanks for the help. Ofcourse, each ListItem should have unique identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I guess issue is with you function

```
GenereerDummyGroepen();
```

Please put your code here. In your code there is value field might have same data for all listItem. Because of that it is changing default to firstIndex as all values are same.

Comment: This does the trick. Sorry for bothering for such an easy solution and many thanks for saving me some days of puzzling!  :)